# executing batch file when called from java project

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

So I'm working on a java project, that at some point I have to execute a batch file (from within the code).

The batch file runs fine if I run it by double clicking in windows explorer,
and/or even if I write the command in the command prompt it runs ok.

However, when i call the file from the java code, the command prompt launches and says that its not a recognized command, program, or batch file.

the patch file looks something like this :

```
ffmpeg -re -i C:/001.mp3 -c:a mp3 -ar 12000 -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

and here's how I call it within the java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\encode.bat");
```

I might add that the command prompt when run by java it runs as administrator and I have included the ffmpeg path to be run by any user anyway.

Excuse me if I have missed any important details and would be happy to provide them if anyone needs further details to answer my dilemma.

why might this be ?

Edit:
i have tried the same code on another pc and it works fine, can someone please explain to me why the command doesnt get recognized when the command prompt gets run through java

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: I think this is a right way, y dont you continue on that ?

Comment: The problem is that the launched command prompt doesn't recognize 'ffmpeg' as a command, even though it runs fine otherwise (e.g launching from windows explorer).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have tried the solutions you suggested but I still get the same result.

Can someone please confirm that the batch file runs fine and its only my pc acting up ?

Comment: *"I have tried the solutions you suggested"*  Show the current code in the closest form to an SSCCE that is possible.  (An SSCCE is not possible with an external API like FFMpeg, but show the Java code as if we could ignore that).  *"Can someone please confirm that the batch file runs fine and its only my pc acting up ?"*  LOL!  What is your budget?  Or ..less funny, SO does not work that way, and given the dependencies (FFMpeg, a batch file, a media file to test it on..) I doubt anyone will do that for free.

Comment: hmmmm .. i see you are not trying to help, and i doubt you have even read the post i have written.

the link you provided in your earlier comment is somewhat irrelevant to my problem, and the solutions u suggested either breaking the string into an array, or using the processbuilder yields same result as the one i used and stated in my question. 

and i dont know what budget/dependencies are you refering to!!, its just 2 lines of code and a free to use library that any moron can download and use ... anyway your help is no longer appreciated